# How to control Qt TextArea contentHeight with images and text?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, textarea

My TextArea content is "dancing" in y-axis switching from only images and images with text.

Images are expected to have width and height equal to font pixelSize (14px), but they don't behave like text.

Measuring font height using FontMetrics, one can see that font have height (19px) greater than pixelSize (14px).

It would satisfy if:

1. generated html paragraph could have a minimum height;
2. could apply padding to image

QML snippet:

```
TextArea {
    id: textArea

    FontMetrics {
        id: fontMetrics

        font: textArea.font
    }

    format: TextEdit.RichText

    (...)

    onTextChanged: {
        InputUtils.imagify(textArea.textDocument, textArea.font)
        var originalText = InputUtils.deimagify(textArea.text)

        console.log("fontMetrics.height: %1; pixelSize: %2; originalText: %3",
                    .arg(fontMetrics.height)
                    .arg(textArea.font.pixelSize)
                    .arg(originalText))

        prettyPrint(textArea.text)
    }
}
```

C++ snippet:

```
void InputUtils::imagify(QTextDocument* document, const QFont& font))
{
    QTextCursor cursor(document);

    while(auto result = findImage(document))
    {
        cursor.setPosition(result->position);

        QTextCharFormat format;
        format.setBackground(Qt::yellow);
        format.setFont(font);
        cursor.setBlockCharFormat(format);

        QTextImageFormat imageFormat;
        imageFormat.setName(result->name);
        imageFormat.setToolTip(result->tooltip);
        imageFormat.setWidth(font.pixelSize);
        imageFormat.setHeight(font.pixelSize);
        cursor.insertImage(imageFormat, QTextFrameFormat::InFlow);
    }
}
```

Printed log for only image:

```
TextArea: expression for onTextChanged | fontMetrics.height: 19; pixelSize: 14; originalText: :-)
```

Generated html for only image:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="qrichtext" content="1" />
      <style type="text/css">p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }</style>
   </head>
   <body style=" font-family:'Graphik'; font-size:14px; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
      <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#0000ff;"><img src="qrc:/images/smile.png" width="14" height="14" /></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Printed log for image and text:

```
TextArea: expression for onTextChanged | fontMetrics.height: 19; pixelSize: 14; originalText: :-) something
```

Generated html for image and text:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="qrichtext" content="1" />
      <style type="text/css">p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }</style>
   </head>
   <body style=" font-family:'Graphik'; font-size:14px; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
      <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#0000ff;"><img src="qrc:/images/smile.png" width="14" height="14" /> something</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @folibis: sorry; I thought it was supposed to be the title; missed the question mark; updated.